# omit empty strings fields mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   x: String,
   y: String
})
```

when a user from the front-end requests in his body:

```js
req.body = {
   'x' : '',
   'y': ''
}
```

this results in creating a field in MongoDB, but with an empty string.
I need a way to prevent this behavior by setting the empty strings to be undefined somehow.

Is there such an option in Mongoose? or do I have to predict my own middlewares for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `set` method for Mongoose Schemas:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    myAttribute: {
      type: String,
      set: (attribute: string) => attribute === '' ? undefined : attribute,
    },
  },
  { strict: 'throw' },
);
```

This will unset the field if the string equals `''`.

Use this to trim the strings:
`set: (a: string) => a?.trim() === '' ? undefined : a`

Comment: You don't need to trim the strings this way, there's already an option for trimming the strings, it's the `trim: true`

Comment: For an input like `'  '` your answer will again store an empty string in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mongoose, or a middleware to handle this.  You can just write a quick few lines to check for empty values and exclude them from the MongoDB write operation.

Ex:

```
const newEntry = Object.entries(req.body).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  if (value) obj[key] = value
  return obj
}, {})
```

In this example, I convert the `req.body` into an array using `Object.entries` and iterate over it with the `Array.reduce` method, wherein I add key:value pairs to a new object if there is a value to add. Since an empty string value is falsey I can do a simple `if` check on the value. I then assign the return of the reduce method to the variable `newEntry`.  Then I would then take the new entry and create the MongoDB document with it.

This could be extracted into a helper method and reused in any of your routes that need to check remove empty values from an object.

Docs on [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Docs on [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: yes, and imagine what if I have nested fields? (or nested fields inside arrays of arrays of objects)

Comment: Interesting.  That increases the scope of the question significantly.  Lots of solutions for recursive nil-check algorithms in JS on stack overflow to explore.  But likely you know the structure of the request body, yes?  You would just need to perform this operation on every instance of an object in your request body, so however you get there, this can be used as a solution.

Comment: @Ps, of course, that's what I'll actually do, and a new issue has been created on the mongoose github page